# how to use $.each to iterarte rows in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Im new to CodeIgniterIm getting data from this controller
Controller:

```
public function selectAll(){
        $this->load->model('EmpModel');
        $res=$this->EmpModel->selectAll();
        if(count($res) > 0){
            echo json_encode(Array("success"=>"1"));
        }else{
            echo json_encode(Array("success"=>"0"));
        }
    }
```

I want to show it in view using $.each()
view:

```
<table id="t_id">
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>email</th>
            <th>pass</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
    </table>
<button type="button" id="subBtn11"  >CLICK</button>
$("#subBtn11").click(function (){
    alert("ok");
   $.ajax({
      url:"<?php echo base_url('index.php/EmpCon/selectAll')?>",
      method:"get",
      dataType:"json",
      data:{

      },
      success:function (data){

          var arr=[];
         var trHTML = '';
              if(data.success==1){  
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {

            trHTML += '<tr><td>' + data.id[i] + '</td><td>' + data.name[i] + '</td><td>' + data.email[i]+'</td><td>'+data.password+'</td></tr>';
        });

        $('#t_id').append(trHTML);
        }else{
        alert("wrong");
        }
      },
      error:function(msg){
      alert(msg.responseText);
      }
   }); 
});
```

I googled the query but aint getting any satisfactory explanation.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You just returns the success key via ajax nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have create Sample for `$.each` Please Check : https://jsfiddle.net/erwzpvok/

You can change your controller file below to get data:

```
//Considering $res contain your data array.
$json = array("status" => "1", "data" =>$res);

echo json_encode($json);
```

And Then Try Below:

```
    var trHTML = '';
      // it might be data.data as per controller.
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
// add all other fields, that you want to show in below trHTML.
      trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.Id + '</td><td>' +item.Name + '</td></tr>';

    });

     $('#t_id').append(trHTML);
```

Comment: $.each is not working. i did data['name'],data['email'] then its showing undefined table data. but nothingg in this case.

Comment: Done.i did item['name'],item['email']...name,email are my columns in database table.Thanks for your help

Comment: done vijay.once again thanks for help.That controller changes were unknown to me.

Comment: Let me know if you need any more help in controller . i will happy to help here.

Comment: definitely.I will post incase of any query

Answer (score 0):

Try like below but you didn't return the object from controller.

```
$.each(data, function (i, item) {

            trHTML += '<tr><td>' + data[i].id + '</td><td>' + data[i].name + '</td><td>' + data[i].email+'</td><td>'+data[i].password+'</td></tr>';
        });
```

Comment: $.each is not working. i did data['name'],data['email'] then its showing undefined table data. but nothing in this case.

Answer (score 0):

pass array in controller when success is 1

```
 public function selectAll(){
        $this->load->model('EmpModel');
        $res=$this->EmpModel->selectAll();
        if(count($res) > 0){
            echo json_encode(Array("success"=>"1","ss"=>$res));
        }else{
            echo json_encode(Array("success"=>"0"));
        }
    }
```

access ss array in $.each()

$.each(data.ss, function (i,item) {

```
           // trHTML += '<tr><td>' + data[i].id + '</td><td>' + data[i].name + '</td><td>' + data[i].email+'</td><td>'+data[i].password+'</td></tr>';
            trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item['id'] + '</td><td>' + item['Name'] + '</td><td>' + item['email']+'</td><td>'+item['password']+'</td></tr>';
        });
```

this is working correctly